# I keep getting an error on my vba code for .autofilter.filtermode due to advanced filtering on my Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, advanced-filter

I have the code below on a Excel sheet where I use slicers as a dashboard through code to manage a separate sheet which filters based on selections made on the slicers.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim lCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set tbl = Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("MasterdataDatabase")
lCol = tbl.ListColumns("xFilter").Index

With tbl
    If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:="TRUE"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set tbl = Nothing
End Sub
```

I recently added code to be able to use the advanced filters to create a customized table on a separate sheet, but I keep getting an error in the line:

```
If .Autofilter.filtermode then
```

I think this is due to the advanced filtering but I'm not sure how to fix it. The code added for the advanced filtering to assist in creating the tables is listed below as well.

```
Sub SubListROW()
Range("fulltabledatabase").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("rngCriteria"), CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "rngExtract"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: ... and `ShowAllData` is also a method of `Worksheet`. Try as `With tbl: 
    If .PARENT.FilterMode Then .PARENT.ShowAllData` where .Parent is the worksheet containing tbl.

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate your help! Your suggestion fixed the issue I was having!

Comment: Oh-key-doh-key then! Do you wish to close this question as a mere typographical error of should I submit a response below in the answers section?